# backbone router path settings

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-routing

I have a path configured for my backbone router as

```
var myApp = myApp || {};

myApp.router = Backbone.Router.extend({

   routes:{
      "somecontent_:id": "content",
      "":"defaultPath"
  },

  defaultPath: function(){
     //default path 
  },

  content: function(id){
     console.log("some new id"+id);
   }
});

myApp.newRouter = new myApp.router();
```

my default path looks like[0] and new path [1]

```
[0]myurl.com/somecontent
[1]myurl.com/somecontent_id
```

Problem: "somecontent_:id"  is not right/have issue and so "content" method is also not get called.

Thanks in advance for any suggestion /advice

edit 1:

I have mentioned my path wrongly . it should be

```
[0]myurl.com/somecontent/one/two
[1]myurl.com/somecontent/one/two#newcontent_id
```

I invoke those router from view as

```
myApp.newRouter.navigate("",true) for [0]
myApp.newRouter.navigate("/newcontent_"+ id, true); for [1]
```

Comment: use a `/` instead of an `_`

Comment: thanks @Simon but I am having issues using '/' instead of "_" . Since that does not fix the issue i tried that too.

Comment: are you getting any console errors?

Comment: you can use "-" insteand of "_". But I think you need to read http://backbonejs.org/#Router-routes in detail. It will help you redesign your routs in better way.